# Is SaveChangesAsync to the database context Ok inside while loops in a .net 5 isolated azure function app

Tags: c#, .net, linq, azure-functions

I have a .net 5 function app that needs to run through a bunch of agreements, checks if they are already being processed by another instance of the function app, and if not locks it by adding the id to a AgreementProcessing table and update as necessary. I am using LINQ.

I always try to save to the database after the for loop, but in this case I need to loop and wait for changes to the agreements for a while, and since there can be multiple instances running at any given time I also need to lock those agreements I am going to process.

This essentially looks like this:

```
while (true)
{
  var dbAgreements = _context.Agreements.Where(a => a.Processed == false && 
                                   a.Status == "PENDING" &&
                                   a.Created.AddMinutes(5) < DateTime.Now &&
                                   !_context.AgreementProcessing.Any(p => p.AgreementId == 
                                   a.AgreementId)).ToList();

  if (dbAgreements == null && dbAgreements.Count == 0)
  {
    return false;
  }

  if (dbAgreementsToProcess != null && dbAgreementsToProcess.Count > 0)
  {
    var dbAgreementsToProcess = await SetAgreementsToProcessing(dbAgreements);      

    foreach (var dbAgreement in dbAgreementsToProcess)
    {
       await ProcessAgreement(dbAgreement);
    }

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    // wait one second and check again
    await Task.Delay(1000);
  }
}
```

A simplified version of **SetAgreementsToProcessing** is shown here:

```
private async Task<List<Agreement>> SetAgreementsToProcessing(List<Agreement> dbAgreements)
{
  List<Agreement> result = null;
  List<Agreement> agreementsToProcess = new List<Agreement>();

  foreach (var dbAgreement in dbAgreements)
  {
    if (CheckIfStatusChanged(dbAgreement)
    {
      AgreementProcessing processing = new AgreementProcessing() { id = dbAgreement.Id};
    }

    _context.AgreementProcessing.Add(processing);

    agreementsToProcess.Add(dbAgreement);
  }

  try
  {
    int dbUpdates = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    if (dbUpdates > 0)
    {
       // only if we get here are there items to be processed
       result = agreementsToProcess;
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      // logs error
  }

  return result;
}
```

So I call SaveChangesAsync twice in the while loop. Once in SetAgreementsToProcessing and a second time after all the agreements have been processed (if no agreements were processed this will do nothing).

I am uneasy about this solution since I as a rule avoid SaveChangesAsync in a loop. I am considering if I should get rid of the while loop and instead, if I get to the end, simply schedule a new instance of the function app to process. I might do that, but other suggestions (or warnings) welcome.

Comment: Create and dispose `DbContext` between delays.

Comment: I inject the context, and I'm not clear how this helps? I have now tested removing the while loop and instead queuing a new run of the function app after each delay and that works very well - at least in my simple and naive test.  I use storage queues, e.g. [QueueOutput("outqueue", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]

Comment: Ok. At least after `SaveChanges` call  `_context.ChangeTracker.Clear()` to remove unwanted entities from tracking.